# Drag and Drop Text over the image using jquery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

i am new to jquery i have the following code but the drag the drop function is not working. The text is updating as expected but the drag is not working. please help

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#title").keyup(update);
});

function update(){        

  var title = $("#title").val();
  $("#Displaytitle").html(title);

  $("#Displaytitle").draggable();
  $("#Displaytitle").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $text = $("#Displaytitle").text();
      $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html($text);
      // $("#msg").hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="title" type="text" class="click" id="title" value=" " size="25" />
  <br/>
  <img  name="pic" class="click" id="photo" src="maritime.jpg" width="500" height="500" />
  <!-- </select> where is the opening tag ? -->
  <br/>
</form>
<!-- </div> where is the opening tag ? -->
<p id="Displaytitle"></p>
```

Comment: You had 2 useless closing tags in your HTML, I have commented them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer [here](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/dd/dnd1.php). it super cool and easy. Thanks every one